# Fetch all rows of the two joined tables at once

Tags: hibernate, jpa, join

I'm trying to write a piece of code to fetch all of the ContactDevices with their associated Contact at once as a list (through execution of only one sql-statement).

```
Criteria sq = session.createCriteria(ContactDevice.class)
                .setFetchMode("contact", FetchMode.JOIN);
List<ContactDevice> contactList = (List<ContactDevice>) sq.list();
```

The problem is for every `ContactDevice`, hibernate fetches it's associated `Contact` through running a separate sql-statement which makes my program considerably slow, I mean hibernate runs this for each `ContactDevice` to get it's associated `Contact` :

```
select * from Contact contact0_ where contact0_.ContactID=?
```

I also tried a seemingly more manual approach but still couldn't prevent hibernate, Is there any way that I can do this by the cost of only running one sql-statement ?

```
@Entity
public class Contact {    
@Id
@Column(name = "ContactID")
private Integer id;    
private String firstName;
private String secondName;    
private String avatarPath;
}

@Entity
public class ContactDevice {    
@Id
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "ContactID", referencedColumnName = "ContactID")
private Contact contact;
private String phoneNumber;
private String deviceType;
}
```

Comment: There's a typo with `setFetchMode`. Should be `contract` (lowercase)

Comment: @orid Changed it to `setFetchMode("contact", FetchMode.JOIN)`, didn't help

Comment: And if you add `fetch=FetchType.EAGER` in @OneToOne ?

Comment: I added `@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)` & `@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)` but works the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks guys, your hints helped me a lot. And at last I figured a way and it was to disable the `proxy` to get rid of this persisting laziness !

```
public class ContactDevice {    
    @Id
    @OneToOne
    @LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY)
    @JoinColumn
    private Contact contact;        
    .....
}
```

Now tuples could be retrived through both

```
Criteria sq = session.createCriteria(ContactDevice.class).setFetchMode("contact", FetchMode.JOIN)
```

or

```
Query query = session.createQuery("select cd from ContactDevice cd join fetch cd.contact");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with a simple HQL query like this:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("select cd from ContactDevice cd join fetch cd.contact");
List list = query.list();
```

Comment: thanks @Vlad, but still runs a separate sql to get associated `contactdevice.contact` when running `query.list()`.

Comment: Don't you think the problem arises from the fact that the foreign-key is the same as the primary-key (in `ContactDevice`) ?

Comment: If it runs a separate query then it's a Hibernate bug. Maybe you missed the fetch keyword.